# Spring and Thymeleaf form validation using modelandview

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

i am having a problem returning the error on thymeleaf template.

i have this on my controller, viewModel is ModelAndView object.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ModelAndView Create(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @Valid @ModelAttribute("viewModel")TViewModel model,
        BindingResult result, Model m) throws Exception {
   if (result.hasErrors()) {
        viewModel.setViewName("maintenance/role/create");
        viewModel.addObject("viewModel", model);
        viewModel.addAllObjects(result.getModel());

        return viewModel;
    }
        return viewModel;
}
```

And this is my view

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <input th:field="*{Description}" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('Description')}" th:errors="*{Description}">Error!</span>
</div>
```

I want to show the `<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('Description')}" th:errors="*{Description}">Error!</span>` when there is an error on description field, can somebody help me with this. i tried every possible way. Thank you.

Comment: Where does viewModel comes from?

Comment: @Flocke viewModel is a ModelAndView object as i said above.

Comment: What is `TViewModel` ?? Won't it `ViewModel` ?

Comment: nope that is the object model, and that is a generic model